# Nginx - How to setup static route IP address with port address?

Tags: nginx, magento, ip, port

I am using the Magento e-commerce platform, installed and using by LEMP.

My Localhost URL : 192.168.1.64:8087/

If i add the following content to **etc/hosts**,

**192.168.1.64:8087 [www.giri.local](http://www.giri.local)**

Url: **[www.giri.local](http://www.giri.local)**

URL Not working, Is it my configuration right? I have doubts about port Address.

What is the right way to declare hosts under etc/hosts:

**192.168.1.64:8087 [www.giri.local](http://www.giri.local)**
(or)
**192.168.1.64 [www.giri.local:8087](http://www.giri.local:8087)**

Comment: The only thing that would work is `192.168.1.64  www.giri.local`, TCP port isn't the subject of domain name resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is..

```
192.168.1.64 www.giri.local
```